# Is it possible to select the highest value of a DENSE_RANK() field as a field?

Tags: oracle, plsql

One of my selects ends with:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY a.distance, a.state || a.idnum, a.taxid, a.location) row_num
```

which gives a row number to the result set, there will be duplicates.

I am wondering how I could use a similar or related statement in the same select to also include a field highest_row_num to get the highest one of all the row_num fields that are created by the above statement. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
select v.*, max(row_num) over () as max_row_num
from 
( select ...,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY a.distance, a.state || a.idnum, a.taxid, a.location) row_num
  from ...
)
```